# Ubuntu 16.04 Boot Error

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have these errors while booting and it takes about 2-3 min to launch Ubuntu 16.04.

```
[sde] No Caching mode page found
[sde] Assuming drive cache: write through lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 233862/13139968 files
EDAC sbridge: Ecc is disabled, Aborting
EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error (`[sde] No Caching mode page found [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 233862/13139968 files`) you fix by changing the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` in `/etc/default/grub`. The second error isn't really a error at all, it is just a warning. If you want it to go away, enable ECC in your BIOS. I don't have this though and never have seen it so it may have side effects. It is a option for your RAM.

Comment: I'm getting only the two "EDAC sbridge" lines, nothing else, and then my boot hangs, so I'm a bit skeptical about them just being warnings. I tried to figure out how to turn on ECC, but can't find an option for it in my BIOS.